# How to convert first Letter of string to uppercase in erlang

Tags: string, erlang, uppercase, erlang-shell

I have a string "data".How can I convert only the first character to uppercase and get a new string in the form of "Data"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the amazing function called [`string:titlecase/1`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/string.html#titlecase-1), like this:

```erlang
1> string:titlecase("data").
"Data"
```

Or… if you don't want to title-case your whole string, but just the first word…

```erlang
5> [First|Rest] = string:lexemes("this data is Nice", [$\s]).
["this","data","is","Nice"]
6> string:join([string:titlecase(First)|Rest], " ").
"This data is Nice"
```

But if you want no fancy string function, you can just use pattern-matching…

```erlang
11> [FirstChar|Rest] = "data".
"data"
12> [string:to_upper(FirstChar)|Rest].
"Data"
13>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the titlecase function in string module.

```
string:titlecase("data").
```